# Questions titles with square brackets in them

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I don't think this should be allowed. I've just edited a couple of question from two different users:

[Why do I get an "rsync: failed to set times on ... : Operation not permitted (1)" error on Ubuntu 10.10 with SME Server 7.4?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10044/rsync-permissions-problem-ubuntu-10-10-sme-server-7-4)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19133/ld-2-14-segfaulting-on-kde-launch-in-archlinux

I edited them because usually square brackets are reserved for [Closed] or [Migrated] tags. Does this bother anyone else?

I kind of a stickler for standard formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different schools of writing titles. Some people prefer titles that are grammatical questions. Others (including me) prefer newspaper headlines. Adding tag words separated by punctuation (brackets or otherwise) is pretty universally frowned upon. I agree with your edits, thank you.

Some of the discussions on the topic:

- [HOWTO: Writing Good Titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/howto-writing-good-titles)
- [Should question titles be phrased as questions? (A straw poll)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19999/should-question-titles-be-phrased-as-questions-a-straw-poll)
- [Warn users before posting if they have a tag at the start of their title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84802/warn-users-before-posting-if-they-have-a-tag-at-the-start-of-their-title)
- [Would the Stack Exchange network be better if titles contained complete, grammatical questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99185/would-the-stack-exchange-network-be-better-if-titles-contained-complete-grammati)

As for disallowing this… How are you going to do that? What about titles that legitimately contain punctuation, like [Triggering a method after a delay without abusing [UIView animateWithDuration]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137591/triggering-a-method-after-a-delay-without-abusing-uiview-animatewithduration) or [What is difference between [pool release] and [pool drain]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139420/what-is-difference-between-pool-release-and-pool-drain) (ok, this one's closed, but as a duplicate; it is missing a word but the brackets are legitimate)? Conversely, why not ban titles like [Django - Using extra clause to retrieve additional data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7140517/django-using-extra-clause-to-retrieve-additional-data) — but how do you do that automatically? There's no way to prevent all the bad ways in which people can ask questions. That's why anyone can edit posts.

Comment: FWIW, there are some *[very limited restrictions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20076/disallow-square-brackets-in-question-titles-opened/100494#100494)* in place for this, but they're unlikely to be expanded for the reasons you note.

Comment: Questions about specific things that include square brackets should be fine. I'm against people tagging in their titles with square bracket -- thats what we have tags for.

Comment: @MaxMackie Yes, I understand. I was just pointing out why it can't be filtered automatically.

Comment: @Gilles: Oh! I didn't mean it to be filtered automatically. Sorry if that's the impression I was giving off. Simply trying to see everyone's standpoint.